# Line break from json to PHP

Tags: php, json, line-breaks

I'm working with the following json code examples:

http://itunes.apple.com/lookup?id=434290957

http://itunes.apple.com/lookup?id=284910350

How can I get the line breaks in the description to appear in PHP?  I think every \n is a line break.  Here's my code thus far.  Thanks for the help!

```
<?php

    $ch = curl_init('http://itunes.apple.com/lookup?id=434290957');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $content = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    $contentdecoded = json_decode($content,true);
    foreach($contentdecoded['results'] as $item) {
        echo $item['kind'] ."<br>";
        echo $item['description'] ."<br>"; 
    }


?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use text/html as MIME type (e.g. on a web page) you'll need to convert the newlines to linebreaks. PHP has a builtin for that: [`nl2br`](http://php.net/function.nl2br).

> nl2br — Inserts HTML line breaks before all newlines in a string

Comment: Great!  Just what I needed.  You guys are awesome.